Displacements on the top face of the cube without breaking the continuity of geometry
I've been trying for a couple of days to create a reusable object for my girls to build a diorama-like worlds. I'm stuck with the water and its displacement.

I set up a cube as a modifier of a plane in Geometry Nodes, then subdivided it into a couple of pieces, gave it a displacement material ("Water").
In material's Shader Nodes I set up a hand-made displacement, basically by separating the top faces by Z value, and multiplying their corresponding normal vectors by some constants, before sending them to Displacement in Material Output.
The outcome for such generated cube is nearly perfect (bumpy top & smooth sides of the cube), but somehow displacement doesn't work on vertices lying on X-axis, with Y coordinate at 0 (see the screen attached).
For a generic cube (placed via Add > Mesh > Cube) the "Water" material displaces only internal vertices of the top face, leaving vertices lying on the edges of the cube intact.


I'm clueless how to fix this or where to go further. What I want to achieve is:

The top face bumpy and displaced, without ripping the continuity of the cube "below" it.
All other faces left untouched, smooth and clear, with their normals pointing outwards
All done in one "Water" shader, with the source geometry in geometry nodes (there will be additional objects there with time, so it will serve as a reusable, parametrized diorama base)

The displacement part of the shader looks like this:

Any help would be appreciated. If the only solution for my challenge is a piece of code, I'm ready for it too - although I've never used any in Blender, I'll be happy to learn something new.
Here's the link to *.blend file on my Google Drive, it may save time creating nodes from the scratch: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15gd8YdXDE67TjU14P8nIg9NuxP31QdS-?usp=sharing
EDIT 01: Here's a picture of the same displacement node setup, but with a  Normal coming from Texture Coordinate node:


(I do not have access to Blender right now, so what follows  is just speculation...) I am suspecting the issue is with the normal computed along edges between perpendicular faces that is "unpredictable" (i.e. very sensitive to the point sampled by the Geometry node). I would rather suggest to store an attribute in the GN modifier based on the normal computed in Face domain. Evaluated in Point domain,  it should be 0 (or very small at least) on constant-X and constant-Y faces. And it should be greater than 0 on constant-Z top faces.

You can also try to recover the Normal using a Texture Coordinate node, instead of a Geometry node. See e.g. Set material based on face orientation

I will take a look in a moment at both of your suggestions. Just writing with a quick check with normals from Texture Coordinate node: they are apparently interpolated as they yield a funny, inverted pyramid-like shape growing up at edges of the cubes, but at least the same in both cases :)
Don't know how to drop a picture of it here, in comments.

OK, I got it. Thank you, @StefLAncien for lighting the spark of inspiration! I just needed a slight push out of my catatonic state :)
Here's what I found out:

The normals are interpolated, so near the top edges of the cube they are slanted towards 45deg and the Z Up face normals are rather (0.707.., 0, 0.707..) than being the expected (0, 0, 1) - thus the pyramid shape.
So, instead of of using the normal provided by Geometry Node, I replaced it with a made-up (0, 0, 1), pure Z Up normal for the top face.
I switch to Z Up vector only when the Z coordinate from the input normal is > 0. This means, in particular, that it might be 0.707.. near the edge, and 1.0 in the centre of the top face.

The modified SN with the switch Normal <-> Z Up and different sources of normals to quickly switch between (on the left):

Here's the result:

Now, the sources of normals this approach works with:

Geometry > Normal: works as expected for both cubes
Geometry > True Normal: doesn't work for neither cubes, giving the result from my original question
Texture Coordinate > Normal: works as expected for both cubes
Attribute > Vector: stored in GN normal works as expected for a cube generated via GN, which is obvious as the other one doesn't have the needed attribute. The normal attribute stored works only in Point and Edge domains, but not in the Face domain.

The modified GN with attribute storing:

I will upload the working Blender file on my drive in a moment.
